# laravel yajra datatable filter column with aditional render data

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

hope some can help me.

I'm using yajra datatables and I want to perform a search in one column, but this column has html code like this:

```
->editColumn('last_connection', function($user){
                            $data = $user->last_connection < Carbon::now()->subDays(7) ? '<label class="badge badge-warning mr-2">Iddle</label>' : "";
                            return $data . $user->last_connection;
                        })
```

This code validates if user last connection was more than 7 days ago, and add a label indicating this.

So, when I search in the datatable i'd like to type "iddle" or the month and should be searching, but no.

This is my custom filter:

```
->filterColumn('name', function($query, $keyword) {
    $query->whereRaw('CONCAT(fname, " ", mname, " ", lname) like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

because you edit the column and modify it with some html, you can't use build in search box to retrieve data ,
you should use and other input/select tag to search this column using search api method provided by jQuery datatable,
its sample for you:

```
var table = $('#your_table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: 'name',
                        name: 'name',

                    },

                    {
                        data: 'last_connection',
                        name: 'last_connection',
                        searchable: false

                    }
                ]});
```

and for your input you can use key-up event to trigger search for specific column in datatable like this

```
 $('#search_last_connection').on('keyup', function() {
                table
                    .columns(1)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
```

or change event for select tag like below:

```
$('#search_last_connection').on('change', function() {
                table
                    .columns(1)
                    .search($("#search_last_connection option:selected").text())
                    .draw();
            });
```

for more information you can use documentation on jQuery datatable [search API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())

Answer (score 0):

if it could help some one, this is how i was able to get it work:

1. Had to add a addSelect in the query (In my case, also spanish translate):

```
DB::statement("SET lc_time_names = 'es_CO';");
$users = User::query()
                ->select('users.*')
                ->addSelect(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(last_connection,'%W %d %M %Y - %r') as last_connection2"));
```

Then customize the filterColumn:

```
->filterColumn('last_connection2', function ($query, $keyword){
        DB::statement("SET lc_time_names = 'es_CO';");
        $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(last_connection,'%W %d %M %Y - %r') like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
})
```